Movie with coincidental visit to Africa and marriage
As far as I can remember, a guy was coincidentally meeting a woman (I think her name started with an 'L') constantly.
When they visited Africa, they, again met. As far as I can remember, there was an assistant, called "Mfana".
Also, one of the guy's daughters was called "ESPN".
Here is what I remember, in general:
Memories start here.
Sometime, the guy wanted to go to  the Safari resort. When he got there, he met (again (again (...))) a woman.
While there, they had (7?) pretty active days and romantic nights together.
After that, they returned with an air balloon, where they got to a baseball court the next day.
While in the court, the air balloon shows up again. After some time passes, they kiss, but, due to an incident in Africa, where the guy said he couldn't kiss her, the woman just did the same, then laughed, then kissed, for real this time.
Memories end here.
It was in English, but I don't remember any of the actors or cast.

This is Blended (2014) with Adam Sandler

After a bad blind date, a man and woman find themselves stuck together at a resort for families, where their attraction grows as their respective kids benefit from the burgeoning relationship.

The daughter called ESPN was a handy google-hook.
I'm not surprised you don't remember it, apparently most people want to forget it.



http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1086772/
